# 3Ware 9500S - Do spare disks spin when not used

Tags: raid, hard-drive, 3ware

Does anybody knows if spare disks connected to a 3Ware 9500s controller will be spinning although not being used? This will wear unnecessarily the disk, possibly spinning for years before a unit gets degraded, thus using the spare unit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the technical support, hot spare designated disks will spin although not being used. 
Maybe it could be worth it to leave the disk unplugged, powering it only when alarms are given.